# Prove $ 3^n>n^2-1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

In the base case $n=0$ it's obvious that the equation holds. So, the induction hypothesis is that $3^n>n^2-1$.

The next step is of course $3^{n+1}>(n+1)^2-1=n^2+2n$

Using our assumption we have: $3^{n+1}>3n^2-3$ And I have to show that right part of this inequality is equal the right part of upper inequality.

*Below is showed my process of thinking.*

\begin{equation}
3^{n+1}>3n^2-3=2n^2+n\cdot n-3>2n^2+n-3
\end{equation}

And in the similar way we have the final result:

\begin{equation}
3^{n+1}>n^2+2n-3
\end{equation}

I have skipped some description and finer points but this is only sketch of a proof. In according to my process of thinking. I removed one of a $n$ in this  $ n\cdot n $ by knowing that $n=1$ satisfies my inequality so I can shuffle it off knowing that the left side will be greater.

**My question is how to get rid of this $-3$?**

Comment: Where is your base step? $n$ is non-negative, in induction.

Comment: @amWhy I assume they decided to leave the base case out as $3^0 = 1$ is obviously larger than $0^2 - 1 = -1$

Comment: $\forall n\ge2,\quad3n^2-3\ge n^2+2n$ (since $2n(n-1)\ge3$). But this doesn't hold for $n=1.$ So, your base case needs to be $n=2.$

Comment: It requires mention, Peder.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, and when that is true then this inequality is all the more true

Comment: Alternate approach: problem reduces to showing that $~\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^2 < 3 ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show $3n^2-3>(n+1)^2-1$. Your estimation failed because you did a very ***coarse*** estimation $n\cdot n>n$ ***twice***!

Try the estimation $n^2>Cn$, where $C$ can be any constant you want.

Answer (score 0):

The induction hypothesis is that $3^n>n^2-1$. You then want to show that
$$3^{n+1}>(n+1)^2-1.$$
Indeed you can expand the right hand side to see that it suffices to show that
$$3^{n+1}>n^2+2n.$$
Then a bit of rearrangement shows that this is equivalent to
$$3\cdot3^n>(n^2-1)+(2n+1).$$
Given the induction hypothesis, this is equivalent to
$$3\cdot3^n>3^n+2n+1.$$
And a bit more rearranging shows that this is equivalent to
$$3^n>\tfrac{n+1}{2}.$$
Now you have a linear function of $n$ on the right hand side, instead of a quadratic. Can you prove this inequality by induction?